# Button Click Border Radius Style Issue

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS. I created a button and I given border-radius to 18px. Everything looks fine, but when I click on that button it showing orange color border as follows. How Can i remove that ?

[image]

Comment: `border:none` or `outline:none`.. though this shouldn't be removed for accessibility reasons.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Outline: none;
```

That should fix this.

Comment: Thanks Sam, wrking like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

`outline: none;` will fix this issue